# The viewer reloads constantly in Edge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have a problem using the viewer in Microsoft Edge. It loads normally but after few seconds it refreshes the entire page and starts over and then a few seconds later it starts over again, never finishing.

We have tested https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=5a7185a92a0a7aeb152725d5 on two different machines both running the latest version of Edge and they both show the same behavior. How do we get around this problem?

[image: Reloading on Edge]

[image: Console log]

Comment: Just tried opening https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=5a7185a92a0a7aeb152725d5 in Edge 42.17134.1.0 (Windows 10 Home 1803), and I don't see any refreshes. Could you provide more info about your system and perhaps a screen recording?

Comment: @PetrBroz I added a video. It is version 42.17134.1.0 of Edge on Windows 10 Pro. I don't have more computers to try on at the moment, but i tried a different network and had the same problem.

Comment: Thanks @Ogge, a couple more questions: have you tried other websites using the viewer (for example, https://viewer.autodesk.com) or do you only see the problem on this particular (React-based) website? And have you tried other browsers? Is there any chance you could collect the console logs before the Edge tab crashes and is reloaded?

Comment: Yes it works in all other browsers, even IE 11. And we have this problem on our own site, but it is not public yet. I have added console log above.

Comment: I see. In that case I'm going to have to ask you to report this issue to forge [dot] help [at] autodesk [dot] com, so that we can forward it to the dev. team.

Comment: And again, please try to collect as much information about the problem as possible, for example, a report from http://webglreport.com would be great, too. Since I can view the Forge RCDB example in Edge without any issues, I'm guessing it could be some specific Edge/hardware combination that's causing this.